# Python Script - mysql.connector doesn't update MariaDB table

Tags: python, mysql, pandas, connection, mariadb

I have been trying to figure out for some time why my python script isn't updating my database.

I have a file called `database.py` and here's what it looks like:

```
    import mysql.connector as mariadb
    import globals

    def connect():
        mariadb_connection = mariadb.connect(user=globals.MY_USERNAME, password=globals.MY_PASSWORD, database='ellen')
        return mariadb_connection

    def insert_author_topics(author_id, topics, cursor):
        sql = "UPDATE author SET topics = \'" + str(topics) + "\' WHERE id = " + str(author_id) + ";"
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql)
        except mariadb.Error as error:
             print("Error: {}".format(error))

    def close(connection):
       connection.commit()
       connection.close()
```

In my main file, I have a function like so:

```
def get_topics(x, ldamodel, cursor, connection):

    author_text = x['processed_text']
    bow_vector = dictionary.doc2bow([author_text])
    topics = '['
    for index, score in sorted(ldamodel[bow_vector], key=lambda tup: -1*tup[1]):
        new_topic = "Score: {}\t Topic: {} ".format(score, ldamodel.print_topic(index, 5))
        topics += new_topic
    topics += ']'
    database.insert_author_topics(author['id'], topics, cursor)
    connection.commit()
```

I have a pandas dataframe of authors, and `get_topics`, which calls `insert_author_topics` is called on every author like so:

```
authors.apply(lambda x: get_topics(x, ldamodel, cursor, connection), axis=1)
```

I have around 100,000 authors in total. For some reason, whenever I run this script, only around 200 authors are updated in the database.

I am not getting any errors when I try to run the script. I tried printing out the ID of every author that gets updated with a sql statement, and I get about 100,000 ID's printed out.

Any help would be appreciated. I can provide more information if needed. Thanks!

Comment: Show us the SQL query after it has been stitched together.  Also, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was in this line of code:

```
database.insert_author_topics(author['id'], topics, cursor)
```

If you look at the arguments I passed to the function, I actually should have been calling `insert_author_topics` like this:

```
database.insert_author_topics(x['id'], topics, cursor)
```

I am not totally sure how this was working without throwing any errors, but glad I finally figured it out!